# Bootstrap carousel makes my footer display on the middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, footer

If I try to display my footer on a page having a Bootstrap Carousel, the footer does not go at the bottom of the page.

If I remove the Carousel, the footer goes to the bottom.

My basic footer is:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2d4wn1aw/1/

Does any one know why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all those `<br>` & switching `position:` to `relative;` on `.footer`

[EDITED: See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d4wn1aw/6/)

[For sticky-footer check here:](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VjZmGj)

Sticky footer is basically a `div` which wraps all content with `min-height: 100%` and negative `margin-bottom` (same height as footer but negative), then another `div` inside this `wrapper` will `push` blank space of the same `height` as the `footer`, leaving room for it (the `footer`), which would go outside the wrapper.

[In case of interest, also a Flexbox sticky-footer example:](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/RRbKrL)

Comment: The same result without the `<br>`

Comment: I edited the Fiddle, forgot `position: relative` in `.footer` as @Ghost pointed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to add wrapper with `position:relative;` then remove those `<br>`
Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgs1L673/1/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to **remove** `position: absolute` in `.footer` or at least **change it to** `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute` property in `.footer` causes the footer to be removed from the flow of elements. By removing this attribute, your footer will respect its position in the DOM (you have it at the end of your HTML, therefore it will be the last piece of content on the page).

Answer (score 0):

```
position:relative
```

is set on carousel and footer has `position:absolute` that means that footer is related to carousel and with `bottom:0` you are saying that footer will be directly after carousel , removing position absolute from footer will make it free and you can use `position:relative` instead,

```css
/* for testing only */
.item img {width: 100%; height: auto}
.carousel,
.item {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    padding:5px;
    
    background-color: #999;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #444;
}

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


        <footer class="footer">Blablabla
        </footer>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I see, but if on another page, there is not enough HTML code to reach the end of the window, the footer will not be displayed at the bottom, but just after the last element.
For example, if we remove the carousel on this example, with position:relative, the footer is not at the bottom.
So, what can I do?

Comment: You mean if we only keep footer , and leave page blank?

Comment: Yes this what I mean

Comment: Footer will be always at the end of body what ever body heigh is , supposing you have an empty page footer will be on bottom of that empty page which has a heigh of 0px + footer height , so if you want to make it look like its a footer you need to add a min-height to body saying 400px;and change footer position from relative to FIXED

Comment: @LondonSmith, what you want in that case is a sticky-footer, I'll edit my answer with that example as well.

Comment: If you want to make full height page, then in all parent blocks add `height:100%;`, also for `body` and `html`.